# Error working with data of a uitable, matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I'm just trying to get some user inputs from an uitable (made with GUIDE), and save this inputs as doubles to calculate another value and put on the uitable
So here is the code...

```
% --- Executes on button press in CTE.
function CTE_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to CTE (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

DATA = get(handles.uitable2,'data');  
for I = 1:5
    s = DATA(1,I);
    d = DATA(2,I);
    u = DATA(3,I);
    p = DATA(4,I);
    t = DATA(5,I);
    r = DATA(6,I);
    c = DATA(7,I);
    a = DATA(8,I);

    if ((2 * s * d * u) > 0) && (((t + r) * c) + (2 * a * (1 - (u / p))) ~= 0)
         X = ((2 * s * d * u) ^ (1 / 2)) / ((((t + r) * c) + 2 * a * (1 - (u / p))) ^ (1 / 2));
    else
       disp('error,ingrese unicamente numeros positivos');   
    end

    DATA(9,I) = X;
end
set(handles.uitable2, 'data', DATA);
```

but I'm getting this error...

Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

```
Error in GuiFinal>CTE_Callback (line 133)
    if ((2 * s * d * u) > 0) && (((t + r) * c) + (2 * a * (1 - (u / p))) ~= 0)
```

Any idea of what is happening, I just don't see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `DATA` is a cell array. You probably need to index it with curly braces:

```
s = DATA{1,I};
d = DATA{2,I};
u = DATA{3,I};
p = DATA{4,I};
t = DATA{5,I};
r = DATA{6,I};
c = DATA{7,I};
a = DATA{8,I};
```

and then later on:

```
DATA{9,I} = X;
```

and at the end of the function, I would do

```
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

For more details, see the doc on [Access Data in a Cell Array](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) and [Store or retrieve GUI data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).